# How to work with Timestamps in Firestore Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Imagine a value of type `timestamp` stored in a document.

```
allow update: if resource.data.customTimestamp.toMillis() == request.time.toMillis()
```

The above code does not work and throws the following error:

> Function not found error: Name: [toMillis].

If I turn that around like this:

```
allow update: if request.time.toMillis() == resource.data.customTimestamp.toMillis()
```

The data acces is denied:

> Simulated data access denied

This is very confusing to me.

#### Question

How do I parse a Firestore `timestamp` to a [Security Rules `Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp)?

[image: Screenshot from Firebase Console]

### Test Project

[image: Stored data]
[image: Rules simulator]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire rule you're writing, along with the description of how you're using the rule to protect data.  Timestamps definitely have a toMillis method, but it's entirely possible you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: @DougStevenson I mean it exactly how I typed it. It does not matter where that code snippet appears because that is the error that will be thrown on execution, everywhere. The data type is `timestamp`. I added a screenshot from the Firebase console. I tried to find the issue in other places, but it seems like this should be working perfectly fine, hence I am asking. All other fields I am accessing in the same rule work as expected, but I copied this as is from the Rules and the simulator throws that exception.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help if you don't show the complete, minimal rule that illustrates the problem (providing an MVCE is the convention on Stack Overflow).  I'm unable to reproduce this on my own without more context.  It seems like you're intentionally censoring your rules and data here, which is making it hard to see the bigger picture.

Comment: @DougStevenson I understand that. I am always trying to illustrate the problem as good as I can. A real road block for me is the fact that I have no idea what is going on in these scenarios. Maybe you can understand that by looking at my updated question where I see a different result turning the statements around. The security rules feedback makes it really hard for me to see through anything. I need to add to what I posted in the question that I know that the access should be granted because I tested this: `request.time.toMillis() - resource.data.customTimestamp.toMillis() < 999999999`

Comment: So basically it is impossible that the statement in my above comment gets denied if everything is working correctly, but I know from turning the statement around (mentioning `resource.data.customTimestamp.toMillis()` first) that there is the `Function not found` error.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am not sure what I am doing differently than you. I actually created a test project just to test it on another database. I added the screenshots to the question. I believe that I am doing something else wrong, but now you can at least see the whole picture.

Comment: @DougStevenson What I wanted to say is that I was able to reproduce it with my exact code sample, which seems really odd. I feel like I am missing an important piece here.

Comment: It looks like the problem is complicated, and might also be a limitation or fault of the simulator. I'm asking around the Firestore team to see how this is supposed to work.

Comment: The first piece of information that you need here is that `request.time` isn't currently supported by the simulator.  You can use it for published rules, but it just won't work in the simulator.  But this is unrelated to the toMillis function not found on timestamp fields in a document.

Comment: @DougStevenson This does, however, explain why I am seeing "access denied" on reversed statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here that are unrelated, but are essentially bugs in the Firstore rules simulator.

First, `request.time` isn't currently simulated.  It's unfortunately that a rule that tries to evaluate this is immediately rejected, rather than giving you a message saying that it's not supported.

Second, the Timestamp object methods that should be available on Timestamp typed fields in a document are broken. Timestamp fields are currently being sent to the simulator as an "empty object" with no methods, so you can't make use of their values in the simulator.

For both cases, published rules should work OK.

Comment: That is honestly great to hear. I am fine with limitations in the simulator because I think that it was a great addition to Firebase and still is like this. Would be great to have an info about limitations on the Simulator tab .

Comment: Well, both of those should be fixed or some workaround provided eventually. The ability to simulate rules definitely will improve over time.

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson, thanks for the information. By the way, is it fixed now?

Comment: @KonstantinGindemit It seems to work now. At the very least, direct equality comparisons work in the emulator (e.g. `request.resource.data.myDateField == request.time` correctly asserts that `myDateField` is `serverTimestamp`)

Answer (score -2):

See [rules.timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.timestamp_).

> #### `rules.timestamp`
>
> Globally available timestamp functions. These functions are accessed
>   using the timestamp. prefix.
>
> value(epochMillis) returns rules.Timestamp

Make a timestamp from an epoch time in milliseconds.

So, wrap it in `value(` `)`

Comment: I mentioned in the question that the data type is specified as `timestamp`.

Comment: One can save a "timestamp" generated via [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) as a string, that's all I was saying that you may not have the native timestamp. Can you show how you generate `.customTimestamp`?

Comment: I have come up with that workaround, but my existing data uses the `timestamp` type.

Comment: Does the above updated answer not work for you? (BTW, I stopped using server side timestamps a while ago. Date.now() strings work fine for me...)